# Do higher voltages cause heating?

Tags: power-consumption, circuit-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around energy consumption in general.

For some background info, I'm an engineering student and am familiar with the usual electrical engineering formulae

Here is what caused me to ask the question:

I live in the US, which, as you know, uses a 120VAC/60Hz system. I was on vacation to another country where they used the 240VAC/50Hz system.

I was using my hair dryer (rated: 125VAC/60Hz, 1875W) one time and noticed that the filament/coil was getting red hot which it didn't back at home. Then I noticed the above mentioned dryer electrical rating.

1. Why did the dryer overheat at the higher voltage (and different frequency for that matter) even though the rated power should have technically drawn lesser current? (I=P/V)
2. What is this rated power consumption (generally mentioned on the appliance) based on? Is it fixed or does it change with the voltage and frequency?

Comment: The heater is just a resistor (well, close enough for this instance). If you apply twice voltage to it, it will consume twice the current (I=V/R), and *four times* more energy (P=V^2/R).

Comment: If you assume the heater is a resistance, and it has some rated wattage and resistance at 120 VAC, and if you plugged it into 240VAC directly, doubling the voltage means doubling the current, which means quarduping of power. Thus the overheat.

Comment: Apply the formulas reasoning as follows. The source voltage is the independent variable. This is because a system of large commercial generators is designed to keep the mains power at the rated voltage when you plug in the hair dryer. In terms of circuit elements we draw this as an ideal voltage source. The hair dryer is the load with rated power not to exceed 1875 W and 125 VAC. We draw this as a resistor/conductor in series with the source. If source voltage increases power developed in the load increases. Resistor heat element is thermal capacitor that gets too hot if power exceeds 1875 W.

Comment: @Justme, No need to assume in this case. The heating element in virtually every heating appliance ever made (hair dryers included) _is_ a resistor.

Comment: @SolomonSlow While the heaters do not have any imaginary impedance component, they are still quite temperature dependent which makes them a bit non-ideal ohmic resistor, and then there is the blower which cools the heater, which makes the temperature dependency even less simple.

Comment: Please stop playing around with mains electricity! Use only products within their rated voltage range.

Comment: "*I'm an engineering student and am familiar with the usual electrical engineering formulae*": So why did you connect a device designed for 110V to 220V, and wondering why it's getting hot? Ever tried connecting an LED to 5V?

Comment: @U.Windl, probably because of the next part: "Then I noticed the above mentioned dryer electrical rating."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yikes! You should count yourself lucky that nothing caught on fire when you did that, and you should never again plug a device into 240 V if it isn't rated for 240 V.

Your hair dryer is more or less a resistor, meaning that Ohm's law applies to it: current = voltage / resistance, or, for short, \$I = V / R\$. The resistance is probably approximately 8 ohms, so if you connect the hair dryer to 120 V, the current can be calculated as

$$I = 120 \ \mathrm{V} \ / \ 8 \ \Omega = 15 \ \mathrm{A}.$$

The formula for power is power = current * voltage, or \$P = IV\$. That formula tells us that the power your hair dryer consumes if it's plugged into 120 V is about

$$P = (15 \ \mathrm{A}) (120 \ \mathrm{V}) = 1800 \ \mathrm{W}.$$

For an electric heater, heat equals power, so while your hair dryer is consuming 1800 W of power, it's producing 1800 W of heat, too.

What happens if you plug it into 240 V instead? Then the current will be approximately

$$I = 240 \ \mathrm{V} \ / \ 8 \ \Omega = 30 \ \mathrm{A} \qquad \text{(yikes!)}$$

and the power will be approximately

$$P = (30 \ \mathrm{A}) (240 \ \mathrm{V}) = 7200 \ \mathrm{W} \qquad \textit{(yowch!)}.$$

And once again, heat equals power, so now the hair dryer is producing 7200 W of heat, which is *way* more than it's designed to produce.

It's true that the hair dryer's rated power is 1875 W, but that rating *only* applies when the hair dryer is connected to its rated voltage (125 V). The hair dryer is not able to adapt to different voltages. It would be *nice* if, when you plugged the hair dryer into a higher voltage, it lowered its current consumption in order to continue to consume the correct amount of power. However, it is not actually able to do that.

Comment: XKCD hair dryer comes to mind: https://what-if.xkcd.com/35/

Comment: an italicized MathJax `yowch!` is just what I wanted today.

Comment: Though as far as I understand, with more power going through the resistor, it'll heat up more, which should bring its resistance up. So the current and power probably won't go as far as the simple calculation would show. At least in the steady state. Then again, the steady state might be that eventually either the hair dryer or the circuit fuse blows...

Answer (score 7):

> *Why did the dryer overheat at the higher voltage*

Ohm's law prevails in simple elemental components like a heater element and, ohm's law tells you that if you double the voltage, the current also doubles (if the heater element's resistance remains constant). This translates to four times the power dissipated by the resistor.

For more complex electrical circuits like switch mode power supplies, they do address this elemental problem and take only the power they need to drive the load and provide power for the switch mode power supply's internal circuits.

> *What is this rated power consumption*

It is usually based on the nominal rated voltage of the device but, as you probably guessed, for more complex electrical items, it can apply broadly across a range of supply voltages without significant change.